# Store matched word from collection in db

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function to match for a bad word. I’m looking to get the word that is matched.

```
Public function store(PostRequest $request){ 
    $post = Post::create($request->validated());
    $warningWords = Word::where('type', 'warning_words')->pluck('content')->toArray();
    if($this->match($forbiddenPhrases, $thought_content)){
        Flagable::create('status' => '2', 'word' => '', 'word_id' => '']);
    }
}

private function match($needles, $haystack){
    foreach($needles as $needle){
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How do I store the matched word in the create statement column ‘word'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to let the function return the word if any was found and let it return null if nothing was found.

```
private function match($needles, $haystack)
{
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            return $needle;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the if statement to check if a word was returned:

```
$word = $this->match($forbiddenPhrases, $thought_content)
if ($word) {
    Flagable::create(['status' => '2', 'word' => $word, 'word_id' => '']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function like this:

```
private function match($needles, $haystack){
     foreach($needles as $needle){
         if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
             return needle;
          }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

and then change you code like this:

```
 Public function store(PostRequest $request){ 
        $post = Post::create($request->validated());
        $warningWords = Word::where('type', 'warning_words')->pluck('content')->toArray();
        if(($word = $this->match($forbiddenPhrases, $thought_content)) !== false){
            Flagable::create('status' => '2', 'word' => $word, 'word_id' => '']);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
   /**
     * Checks and returns all forbiddenPhrases found in the content
     * 
     * @param  array  $forbiddenPhrases
     * @param  string $content
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    private function match(array $forbiddenPhrases, string $content){

        $content = strtolower($content);
        $forbiddenPhrases = array_map('strtolower', $forbiddenPhrases);

        return  array_filter($forbiddenPhrases, function($word){

            return str_contains($content, $word);
        });
    }
```

Then in controller you can do :

```
$forbiddenPhrases = Word::where('type', 'warning_words')->pluck('content', 'id')->toArray();
$foundForbiddenPhrases = $this->match($forbiddenPhrases, $content);

if(count($foundForbiddenPhrases) > 0){

    foreach ($foundForbiddenPhrases as $phraseId => $foundForbiddenPhrase) {
        Flagable::create('status' => '2', 'word' => $foundForbiddenPhrase, 'word_id' => $phraseId]);
    }
}
```